# Критика решений задач на арифметику и сортировку

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Привет! Читаю книгу, после каждой главы - задания.

Пользователь вводит числа через пробелы. Программа должна выводить:

1. Четные числа
2. Нечетные числа
3. Наибольшее число
4. Наименьшее число
5. Числа, которые делятся на 3 или на 9 (без остатка)
6. Числа, которые делятся на 5 и на 7 (без остатка)
7. Элементы, расположенные методом пузырька по убыванию модулей
8. Трехзначные числа, в записи которых нет повторяющихся цифр
9. Наибольший общий делитель
10. Наименьшее общее кратное
11. Простые числа
12. Числа, отсортированные по возрастанию
13. Числа, отсортированные по убыванию
14. Числа в порядке убывания частоты встречаемости

Требуется критика кода. Представьте, что вы смотрите код на собеседовании.

```
public class Main
{
static Integer[] bubble;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //setup
    System.out.println("Введите числа через пробелы");
    String[] arr = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ");
    ArrayList<Integer> ch = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> unch = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ch39 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ch57 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> z300 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
    bubble = new Integer[arr.length];
    int min = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]); 
    int lcm = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
    int max = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]); 
    int nod = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
    //logic
    for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++)
    {
        String s = arr[x];
        int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        bubble[x] = i;

        min = Math.min(min, i);
        max = Math.max(max, i);
        if (Math.abs(i % 2) == 0) ch.add(i);
        else unch.add(i);
        if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 9 == 0) ch39.add(i);
        if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) ch57.add(i);
        if (s.length() == 3)
        {
            String a = s.substring(0, 1);
            String b = s.substring(1, 2);
            String c = s.substring(2, 3);
            if (! a.equals(b) && ! b.equals(c) && ! c.equals(a))
            {
                z300.add(i);
            }
        }
        nod = gcd(nod, i);
        lcm = lcm(lcm, i);

        int b;
        int num;

        for (b = min; b <= max; b++)         
        {             
            int counter = 0;      
            for(num = b; num >= 1; num--)
            {
                if(b % num==0)
                {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
            }
            if (counter == 2)
            {
                if(!primes.contains(b))
                primes.add(b);
            }   
        }   
    }
    //unch
    System.out.print("\nНечетные : ");
    for (int unchitem : unch) System.out.print(unchitem + ", ");

    //ch
    System.out.print("\nЧетные : ");
    for (int chitem : ch) System.out.print(chitem + ", ");

    //ch39
    System.out.print("\nДелятся на 3 или 9 : ");
    for (int ch39item : ch39) System.out.print(ch39item + ", ");

    //ch57
    System.out.print("\nДелятся на 5 и 7 : ");
    for (int ch57item : ch57) System.out.print(ch57item + ", ");

    //z300
    System.out.print("\nТрехзначные числа без повторяющихся цифр : ");
    for (int z300item : z300) System.out.print(z300item + ", ");

    sort();
    System.out.print("\nПо возрастанию : ");
    for (int upitem : bubble) System.out.print(upitem + ", ");

    unsort();
    System.out.print("\nПо убыванию : ");
    for (int downitem : bubble) System.out.print(downitem + ", ");

    bubbleSort();
    System.out.print("\nПузырек : ");
    for (int bubbleitem : bubble) System.out.print(bubbleitem + ", ");

    final ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(bubble));
    Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs) {
                int compareFreq = Collections.frequency(array, rhs) - Collections.frequency(array, lhs);
                return compareFreq != 0 ?
                    compareFreq :
                    rhs - lhs;
            }
        });

    System.out.print("\nЧисла в порядке убывания встречаемости : ");
    for (int primesitem : array) System.out.print(primesitem + ", ");

    System.out.print("\nПростые числа : ");
    for (int primesitem : primes) System.out.print(primesitem + ", ");


    //min & max & nod & nok
    System.out.println("\nМинимальное число: " + min);
    System.out.println("Максимальное число: " + max);
    System.out.println("Наибольший общий делитель: " + nod);
    System.out.println("Наименьшее общее кратное: " + lcm);
}

public static int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0) return Math.abs(a);
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}

public static int lcm(int a,int b){
    return a / gcd(a,b) * b;
}

public static void bubbleSort()
{
    for (int i=bubble.length - 1;i > 0;i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < i;j++)
        {
            if (Math.abs(bubble[j]) <= Math.abs(bubble[j + 1]))
            {
                int tmp=bubble[j];
                bubble[j] = Math.abs(bubble[j + 1]);
                bubble[j + 1] = Math.abs(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}   

public static void sort()
{
    for (int i = bubble.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (bubble[j] >= bubble[j + 1])
            {
                int tmp = bubble[j];
                bubble[j] = bubble[j + 1];
                bubble[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void unsort()
{
    for (int i = bubble.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (bubble[j] < bubble[j + 1])
            {
                int tmp=bubble[j];
                bubble[j] = bubble[j + 1];
                bubble[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD**

Как мог упростил.

```
public class Main
{
    public static ArrayList<Integer> nums;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Введите числа через пробелы");
        String[] arr = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ");
        nums = new ArrayList<>();

        //перевод в Integer
        for (String str : arr)
        {
            nums.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
        }

        //создаем списки
        ArrayList<Integer> ch, unch, ch39, ch57, z300, primes;
        ch = new ArrayList<>(); //для четных
        unch = new ArrayList<>(); //для нечетных
        ch39 = new ArrayList<>(); //для делимых на 3 или 9
        ch57 = new ArrayList<>(); //для делимых на 5 и 7
        z300 = new ArrayList<>(); //для трехзначных без повторений цифр
        primes = new ArrayList<>(); //для простых

        int first = nums.get(0);
        int min = Collections.min(nums);
        int max = Collections.max(nums);
        int nod = first;
        int lcm = first;

        for (Integer i : nums)
        {
            String s = "" + i;
            if (Math.abs(i % 2) == 0) ch.add(i);
            else unch.add(i);
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 9 == 0) ch39.add(i);
            if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) ch57.add(i);
            if (s.length() == 3)
            {
                String a = s.substring(0, 1);
                String b = s.substring(1, 2);
                String c = s.substring(2, 3);
                if (! a.equals(b) && ! b.equals(c) && ! c.equals(a))
                {
                    z300.add(i);
                }
            }

            nod = nod(nod, i);
            lcm = nok(lcm, i);

            for(int r =2; r <= i/2; r++)
            {
                if(i % r != 0)
                {
                    primes.add(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        output("Четные", ch);
        output("Нечетные", unch);
        output("Делятся на 3 или 9", ch39);
        output("Делятся на 5 и 7", ch57);
        output("Трехзначные числа без повторяющихся цифр", z300);
        output("Простые числа", primes);

        //сортируем по возрастанию
        sort(false);
        output("По убыванию", nums);

        //переворачиваем список и получаем список по возрастанию
        Collections.reverse(nums);
        output("По возрастанию", nums);

        //сортируем по частоте встречаемости
        Collections.sort(nums, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs)
            {
                int compareFreq = Collections.frequency(nums, rhs) - Collections.frequency(nums, lhs);
                return compareFreq != 0 ? compareFreq : rhs - lhs;
            }
        });

        output("Числа в порядке убывания встречаемости", nums);

        //сортируем по убыванию модулей
        sort(true);
        output("По убыванию модулей", nums);

        System.out.println("\nМинимальное число: " + min);
        System.out.println("Максимальное число: " + max);
        System.out.println("Наибольший общий делитель: " + nod);
        System.out.println("Наименьшее общее кратное: " + lcm);
    }

    public static int nod(int a, int b)
    {
        if (b == 0) return Math.abs(a);
        return nod(b, a % b);
    }

    public static int nok(int a, int b)
    {
        return a / nod(a, b) * b;
    }

    public static void sort(boolean bubble)
    {
        if(bubble) {
        for(int b = 0; b < nums.size(); b++)
        nums.set(b, Math.abs(nums.get(b)));
    }

    Collections.sort(nums, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs)
            {
                if(rhs > lhs) return 1;
                else if(rhs < lhs) return -1;
                else return 0;
            }
    });
}   

public static void output(String text, List<Integer> list){
    System.out.print("\n" + text + " : ");
    for (int i : list) System.out.print(i + ", ");
}
```

Comment: Под конец поторопился и забыл о порядке. Сделал на скорую руку. Прошу, покажите на минусы кода

Comment: Код-стайл: скобки!

Comment: @post_zeew, done

Comment: Основной пофигизм пошёл когда я понял что нельзя научить `split` возвращать числа. Заметно, что `String` и `Integer` во всем коде мешают

Comment: Имена переменных кстати тоже. Обратите внимание, я из правильно называл просто потом все изменилось а переименовывать уже и не хотелось :)

Comment: лучше будет если вы вынесите функционал в отдельные методы - так их будет удобнее смотреть. и подумайте о том, что бы использовать новые возможности Java 8.

Comment: Окей сейчас начну код реконструировать

Comment: и лучше если в методы будут передаваться параметры, а не "глобальные" переменные как у вас.

Comment: Я изменил логику немного, посмотрите

Comment: Обратите внимание на комментарий с багом.

Comment: Баг исправлен. Ребят, так что? Хорошо, нет?

Comment: почему подобный вопрос не задать на http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @BogdanK, потому что его [можно задать у нас](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе неплохо. Где-то на 4-ку.

Небольшие замечания:

1. Не выдерживается стиль операторов `if/else/for` в случаях когда в теле есть 1 оператор. Вы либо пишите их без скобок и с новой строки или со скобками.
2. Хорошо бы таки сделать хоть какие-то классы, а не все пихать через `static`
3. Метод `output()` надо сделать чтобы принимал `PrintStream`, тогда можно будет отправлять хоть куда, например в файл - но это уже придирки.

P.S. `Collections.sort()` - сортирует методом [Quick Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) - условия задачи это разрешают?

Comment: Спасибо за критику ;)